# Assets doesn't compile in one file at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm new in Rails and I'm developing an application using Rails 3.2.0. So, when I work at my local machine all is good, pages have design expected with the following head:

```
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="XWFSZcrp1zLXPwqKvANdCgQWr4ws6sM2xqylAYVprrQ=" name="csrf-token" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
```

But then I do a commit and push it to Heroku:

```
git push heroku
```

But my pages don't have design needed; the head of some page on Heroku:

```
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <link href="/assets/application-7270767b2a9e9fff880aa5de378ca791.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/application-3428e82709d7645135002c8fadfafdc6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="lSpfx/uG7gZoccxRHqdFBEQArAvQfI/EYXC/G/V79aU=" name="csrf-token" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
```

I don't know why but "application-....css" file is absolutely clean! How can I fix it? My production.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

What should I change? May be some settings in production.rb must be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku precompiles assets from your application.css file. You shouldn't specify the various css files in the header of the page, which is what it looks like you're doing. You need to make sure that they're in the folder with your application.css file and that your application.css file has the following:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

The `*= require_tree .` line is the important one. It makes sure it picks up all the css files in the folder and loads them in.

Comment: I don't specify stylesheets in layout, Rails does it. I've just putted  my css files into view directory. My application.css file is the same with yours.

Comment: Your CSS files should be in the same directory as your application.css

Comment: So your css files are all in the `/assets/stylesheet` directory and in the header of your `/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file you only reference `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`?